# WooCommerce products on product page fixed size - how to?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how I can change the heights of the products on my shop page to be a maximum and minimum height, and or just fixed. I don't want them to all be different.

here is a link to show you: http://orbetinternational.com/shop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways, via CSS:

```
.products li {
    height: 423px;
}
```

Comment: Well, although that did work. the lines and the add to cart stay at the top still

Comment: Then add css to fix it. You asked for consistent product height, which this answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though the answer above was correct, but would cause a conflict with other items on the page, throwing the layout off.

the way I fixed this issue was by setting a minimum width for the image div and setting a height for the title div

```
.product-images {
min-height:270px;
}
.product-title {
height: 75px;
}
```

This caused no conflicts with anything else and I acquired the desired result.